# Using C library with different data structure

Tags: c++, c, interface

I have a question about the best way to write computing code as flexible as possible in C++, I give you this example:

I am writing a code that manipulates meshes (Finite Element computation), basically set of nodes and connectivities. We only focus on Node structure for now:

```
struct Node { double x,y,z; };
```

I have a set of algorithm implemented using this Node data structure.

However I want to use an external library that provides specific geometrical treatment on meshes (writen by a collegue), it has a different data structure for Node

```
struct LibNode { double x; int idx; double y,z;};
```

note: *int idx is used in the library, I do not need/want it in my own developpement.*

All the algorithms of this library are written with this structure.
I am just using the library, for me it is just a set of treatment that I can apply to the mesh I am using for computing.

I want to use the algorithm in the library written in C, so here are the solutions I imagine:

- make a copy of my Nodes to some LibNode, simplest solution, but very unefficient !
- rewrite my code with LibNode, but what if I want to use several libs ?
- rewrite the lib !

I have several questions here:

- **Am I missing a better solution ?** I feels like whatever I do I cannot avoid using library's data structure.
- As performance is an issue, for now I think that rewriting the lib will be the best solution. Then I will write it in C++, and I do not want to make the same mistake than for the original lib.
  I see two options, template implementation of the lib, more "elegant" but also more difficult to write and maintain by a team of physicists stucked to F77.
  Or manipulating the mesh through an abstract class and delegate the data structure definition to the user of the lib. **But access data through virtual method (more than a million time by code run) seems to be greatly inefficient to me, am I right** ?

Thank you in advance for your response !

Comment: Are you using a library "that manipulates meshes, basically set of nodes and connectivities"? Then why are you writing your own library to duplicate the library you use? Or are you adding another layer on top of a lower-level library? Are you extending the library you use? Maybe your own structure should be an opaque structure (similar to the standard C `FILE` structure)? Or maybe your structure should incorporate the library structure somehow? Can you please elaborate on the responsibilities of your library, versus the library you use?

Comment: I have updated the post.    I am not extending the lib or building a top layer, it is just a set of treatment that can be useful for me. I definitly want to use it, not more.  I understand what you propose for opaque structure, but then the library should also use it, right ?

Comment: Perhaps you should incorporate the libraries structure into your own, like `struct MyNode { struct LibNode libnode; /* other data needed exclusively for your library */ };`? If you do it like that, you are basically emulating inheritance in C, and can pass pointers to your structure to functions expecting pointers to `LibNode`.

Comment: It was one of my options for sure ! But this brings two problems: I have to adapt my code to use the library, then what if I use two ? Then my struct should contain several "copy" of the same data.

Comment: Does idx need to be set or is it set to a fixed value or is it just working storage used by the program?

Comment: It really depends on the libraries, and what you're using them for. There's no one single generic answer.

Comment: I add it in the post, it is a rather important comment !  idx is used in the library, not in my code. The developper of the lib put idx here for convenience but I do not need/want that in my code !

Comment: I think it would be really important to add some function signatures and descriptions from the library here. Generally there should be a couple of ways to do this like using implicit conversions or just adding the int in your struct, but if a member is called idx, which is typically short for index, then the library may expect certain invariants to be true for a set of node. So without seeing how it is used I think there is a good chance to send you down the wrong path.

Comment: The question is too broad, there is no single canonical answer.

Comment: To midor:  I have the library's code, and i can tell you that "idx" is a bad choice of name for what it aims at. It is an internal label for marking space, this variable is only used in the library, I do not have to provide it, and I do not want to get the value either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is conformant C, the simplest way would be to rebuild the library using `Node`, just changing Node to `struct Node { double x; int idx; double y,z;};`. All access to members `x`, `y` and `z` should work correctly, and the `idx` node will be processed more or less as padding. After all, that is one of the best points on using structs for maintaining applications: you can add members with no or little change to existing code

Of course if you assume somewhere that `&node.y == &node.x + 1` everything will break...

The only thing I can think about that could be problematic would be loading structs that would have been saved as a whole to a binary file. That part (and the save part) should be rewritten  to explicitely save and restore members and not the whole whole struct - anyway saving a whole struct is non portable and should be avoided if possible.

Another problem, mainly if it is used as a DLL, is that it will be a major change because it will break compatibility, so you should considere to rebuild all programs using your library.

Comment: Well, it feels like there is no walk around to introducing the data structure from the lib in my own code, at least for most of the case like this.